# Directing the search depths in Crawler4j Solr

Tags: java, solr, crawler4j

I am trying to make the crawler "abort" searching a certain subdomain every time it doesn't find a relevant page after 3 consecutive tries. After extracting the title and the text of the page I start looking for the correct pages to submit to my solr collection. (I do not want to add pages that don't match this query)

```
public void visit(Page page)
{
    int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
    String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
    String domain = page.getWebURL().getDomain();
    String path = page.getWebURL().getPath();
    String subDomain = page.getWebURL().getSubDomain();
    String parentUrl = page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();
    String anchor = page.getWebURL().getAnchor();

    System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
    System.out.println("URL: " + url);
    System.out.println("Domain: '" + domain + "'");
    System.out.println("Sub-domain: '" + subDomain + "'");
    System.out.println("Path: '" + path + "'");
    System.out.println("Parent page: " + parentUrl);
    System.out.println("Anchor text: " + anchor);
    System.out.println("ContentType: " + page.getContentType());

    if(page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
        String title, text;

        HtmlParseData theHtmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
        title = theHtmlParseData.getTitle();
        text = theHtmlParseData.getText();

        if (  (title.toLowerCase().contains(" word1 ") && title.toLowerCase().contains(" word2 "))  ||  (text.toLowerCase().contains(" word1 ") && text.toLowerCase().contains(" word2 ")) ) {
            //
            // submit to SOLR server
            //
            submit(page);

            Header[] responseHeaders = page.getFetchResponseHeaders();
            if (responseHeaders != null) {
                System.out.println("Response headers:");
                for (Header header : responseHeaders) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
                }
            }

            failedcounter = 0;// we start counting for 3 consecutive pages

        } else {

            failedcounter++;

        }

        if (failedcounter == 3) {

            failedcounter = 0; // we start counting for 3 consecutive pages
            int parent = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();
            parent....HtmlParseData.setOutgoingUrls(null);

        }
```

my question is, how do I edit the last line of this code so that i can retrieve the parent "page object" and delete its outgoing urls, so that the crawl moves on to the rest of the subdomains.
Currently i cannot find a function that can get me from the parent id to the page data, for deleting the urls.

Answer (score 0):

The `visit(...)` method is called as one of the last statements of `processPage(...)` (line 523 in `WebCrawler`).

The outgoing links are already added to the crawler's `frontier` (and might be processed by other crawler processes as soon as they are added).

You could define the behaviour described by adjusting the `shouldVisit(...)` or (depending on the exact use-case) in `shouldFollowLinksIn(...)` of the crawler